# Adding object field inside of merged array and array reverse

Tags: javascript

there is some code like that

```
let array = [{name:"a"},{name:'b'},{name:'c'}];
let newArray = [...array,...array.reverse()];
newArray[0].id = 1;
```

output is

```
[{"name":"a","id":1},{"name":"b"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"b"},{"name":"a","id":1}]
```

as you can see id field will adding all fields with {"name":"a"} so i want to add field just indexed (0) object. I try to slice array then reverse array thats not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an array that has a clone of each object inside the array and not a reference, so array.slice won't work. The simplest solution, IMO, is to just use `JSON.parse/stringify` like below then modify the first item of the first array.

```js
let array = [{name:"a"},{name:'b'},{name:'c'}];
let arrayClone = array.map(item => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)));
arrayClone[0].id = 1;
console.log(arrayClone, array);
let newArray = [...arrayClone,...array.reverse()];

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray));
```